# Can I create an element with forward slash as part of the name

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

Can i create an element with forward slash as part of the name?

```
<Data>
<DataRow>
<Orange/Apple> fruit </Orange/Apple>
</DataRow>
</Data>
```

seems invalid to me but just want to confirm.

Comment: I don't see what your question body has to do with your question title. A forward slash isn't 0x20...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can i create an element with forward slash as part of the name?

No, according to [the grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name) pulished on the W3.org website it is not a valid character in a name.

> hexadecimal value 0x20 cannot be included in a name

`0x20` is the space character and you will see that it is not on the list of valid NameChars. It is considered whitespace unless it is part of a value.